# About saving data using linq with foreign key

Tags: c#, linq, foreign-keys

I encounter a problem where this involve foreign key using linq query to do. It's like this, I have 2 tables, "station" and "location". They are linked to another table, "locationstation" using their primary. I need to catch the Station Name from the "station" table and the location at the "location" table.

This is the code I use to join all 3 tables and showed it in the data grid view.

```
private void Create_LS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            var storeStation = (from SLS in Setupctx.locationstations
                                        join station s in Setupctx.stations on SLS.idStation equals s.idstations
                               select s.Station1).Distinct().ToList();                                   
            foreach (var LocationStation in storeStation)
            {
                cbStation.Items.Add(LocationStation);
            }

            var storeLocation = (from SLS in Setupctx.locationstations
                                join location l in Setupctx.locations on SLS.idLocation equals l.idlocation
                                select l.Location1).Distinct().ToList();                                      
            foreach (var LocationStation1 in storeLocation)
            {
                cbLocation.Items.Add(LocationStation1);
            }
        }
    }
```

After completing in showing into the data grid view, I bind the station name and the location name into 2 respective combo box. This is the codes that I bind into.

```
string selectStation = cbStation.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string selectLocation = cbLocation.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

After that, I need to create new "locationstation" by selecting the station and location using the combo box. How do I do that? The column name under "locationstation" is still the id of "station" and "location" How to actually creating new locationstation? i'm lost.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @marc_s erm okay. Some were solved without here so yea. I'm asking for help for this urgently, it seems like nobody knows how to solve.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you actually talking about? Can you give me solutions for me to approach on?

Comment: @Philemon If you found the answer from somewhere else you could post it on the question yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You're close - you just need to grab the **whole** selected object when you're done - not just the name as a string:

```
Station selectedStation = cbStation.SelectedItem as Station;
Location selectedLocation = cbLocation.SelectedItem as Location;
```

Now, you have access to all the necessary properties on that object - you can extract the `Name`, the `ID` and whatever else you might need to build up your new entity (or entities).

Comment: locationstation creLS = new locationstation();
                creLS.idStation = selectStation();

i declare this locationstation table because i wanted to save whatever the user choose for the station and location. but the creLS only have idstations and idlocations that cannot be linked to what is inside the combo box. Any idea after your codes because my way doesn't work with your declaration you gave me on top.